# How can I make a click counter in dreamweaver in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, dreamweaver

I'm creating a website, that has a button, I want it to work in such way that whenever someone clicks it a number is increased by one, I want this number not to be reset when the page is refreshed or accessed from somewhere else.
Please help me with a sample code... Im a beginner

Comment: You need server-side code and persistent storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @SLaks, you will need some method of storing this counter on the server - otherwise there is no way for a page request to know how many times it has been called before. To do this you will need both:

1. Server-side code to read the value and display it to the user, and also to update the value when the page is requested the next time, and
2. Server-side storage to actually hold the counter value.

One possible solution to this (without adding a huge amount of additional complexity) would be to use PHP to read/write the counter, and a simple text file to hold the value. There are other ways, but may make things a bit too hard (i.e. no need for a database to hold one value).